# Aggregate function vs manual count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have tickets collection which I fetch from a web api, right now I have about 20,000 tickets but this collection will group upto 1 million or more.

I want to calculate how many tickets are open closed by company wise.

I have two ways:

1. store tickets in db and then use aggregate function
2. while fetching tickets I calculate the manually by using counter

Tell me which way is good?

P.S Is aggregate function is costly? Does it slow down the db performance?

Comment: Pre-calculation is preferable if you update your data rarely, but query very often. If it's the other case (rare reads, frequent updates), then you want to sacrifice some performance to get up-to-date results.

Comment: @sergio please explain more

Answer (score 1):

There can be different approaches, but i certainly not propose to do aggregate on this much huge data on runtime, neither i suggest you the pre-calculation and discard the api data.

I will just make a collection to keep all api data, and then make a summary table which has the opening and closing tickets count only, in this way your data is preserved and hence your performance.

And yea, aggregation framework is costly, and on this much data you explicitly need to specity `allowDiskUse: <boolean>` and `

> While aggregate is performed it slow down the `collection` not the
>   database, as `wiredTiger Storage Engine` doesn't lock the database, rather it locks at document level for read write operations.
>   `

[WiredTiger - MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#how-granular-are-locks-in-mongodb)

Comment: if data is small like 20,000 then ?

Comment: right now I am adding the counters while fetching data from the api 
I store the counts in summary table and the api data in other table
Is this a good approach ?

Comment: yes if data is small then it's alright. then aggregate don't consume a lot of memory and it is efficient.

Comment: right now I am adding the counters while fetching data from the api I store the counts in summary table and the api data in other table Is this a good approach ?

Answer (score 1):

Index the field that says if are oppened and perform a count (or global count, I don't understand what you mean with "open close open closed by company wise").

Will be fast and you doesn't needs an aggregation to perform this simple count haha